# Global deno.json configuration file?

Tags: deno

I want to apply this deno.json configuration file to all my deno projects:

```json
{
    "fmt": {
        "options": {
            "indentWidth": 4
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to globally apply this configuration so I don't have to have this deno.json file in every project?

I'm using VSCode, Ubuntu and Deno 1.28.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because of the way that the Deno VS Code extension overrides/suppresses the built-in TS language server, it is not advised to enable the extension globally: this would cause problems in every non-Deno TypeScript project.**

That said, you can create a single `deno.json(c)` file at a high-level location in your filesystem — for example: in your home directory. To use a concrete example location — on Linux — `/home/your_username/deno.json`.

Then, when configuring a new VS Code project, you only need to configure the location of the config file in `.vscode/settings.json` in order for the extension to use it:

```json
{
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.config": "/home/your_username/deno.json"
}
```

---

When using Deno in the CLI, it will automatically walk your filesystem and find the nearest parent config file. From [the manual](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.1/getting_started/configuration_file#configuration-file):

> [Since v1.18](https://deno.com/blog/v1.18#auto-discovery-of-the-config-file),
> Deno will automatically detect `deno.json` or `deno.jsonc` configuration file if
> it's in your current working directory (or parent directories).

---

Regardless of the above, this strategy is not advised: a better approach might be to simply to create a personal CLI script/function which will generate a new deno config and VS Code config from a template that you create. This way, each of your projects maintains its own configuration data (a good thing) and you also don't have to manually configure each new one because you did the work once to create the template generation script (win-win).